# Inconsistent behaviour with with regard to displaying properties using: svn log --with-all-revprops --xml [URL]

Tags: xml, svn, properties

Firstly, thanks for taking the time to read this and possibly comment on it.

**Summary**

After setting a custom SVN property on a file and committing, I cannot get the "svn log" command, with various options set, to display the property after I commit it. I have followed this [example](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.props.why) from the SVN redbook to no avail (Searchability sub-section).

**My environment**

Server: I am using 32-bit SubVersion Server version 1.6.15 running on 64-bit Windows Server 2008 R2

Client: TortoiseSVN 1.6.16 running on 32-bit Windows XP Pro SP3.

The repo is a test repo with no hooks of any kind available.

**My scenario**

After setting a custom property named *active-projects* on a a file named *test.txt* and committing that change to the repository I attempt to execute the following:

```
svn log --with-all-revprops --xml [url_to_test.txt]
```

The use of the *--with-all-revprops* is supposed to show me my custom *property* but alas, the above returned valid information in XML format but did not include the *revprops* element with a *property* named *active-projects* and its respective value.

Attempting to execute the following in the local directory, containing *test.txt* yielded the same results as above:

```
svn log --with-all-revprops --xml test.txt
```

What is interesting is that I can see the above property on that file at that URL via my repo browser. If I execute the following in the local directory, containing *test.txt*, the value of the *property* is returned as expected:

```
svn propget active-projects test.txt
```

**Conclusions**

So, any ideas why I cannot find my precious *active-projects* custom *property* via the *svn log* command using either the URL or the local path? It may be that I have misunderstood the concept or am missing some vital piece of server configuration. Your insight is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a very detailed and well-written question.

Comment: Thank you jtbandes - I'm nothing if not meticulous :)  - I have been taken off this project for a time but when it heats up again, if I figure it out, I shall post a reply to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing **revision properties** and **regular properties**. Revision properties are set for the whole revision and only apply to that revision (they are *unversioned*), regular properties are set per item (directory/file) and are *versioned* (i.e. if you change them they'll still be there for earlier revisions of the item; they can be diffed, etc.).

You've set an item property, while `svn log --with-all-revprops` returns revision properties, not item properties.

Here's some more info from `svn propset --help`:

```
$svn propset --help
propset (pset, ps): Set the value of a property on files, dirs, or revisions.
usage: 1. propset PROPNAME PROPVAL PATH...
       2. propset PROPNAME --revprop -r REV PROPVAL [TARGET]

1. Changes a versioned file or directory property in a working copy.
2. Changes an unversioned property on a repository revision.
 (TARGET only determines which repository to access.)
```

Hope this clears the confusion.

Comment: Thanks malenkiy_scot. You have really cleared that up for me and since I now understand it, I have since found an example of what I was looking for at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296795/how-to-set-a-property-in-svn-for-a-single-revision-of-a-single-file)